# How to move the contents of a chest to a Bundle using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm currently trying to move the contents of a chest into a bundle (being held by a placeholder armor stand) but the most it would do is copy the last item in the chest (that is not `minecraft:air`) into the bundle.

**Here is the command for reference:**

```
/data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,limit=1] HandItems[0].tag.Items[] set from block 4 -60 11 Items[]
```

(For reference I'm using Minecraft Release 1.18.1)

Comment: Hi, why not repeat the command some few more times to move all items into the bundle?

Comment: Since everytime the last item gets moved all would be displaced anyways

Comment: @hfanatic just tried doing something like that but it sadly didn't work since I used "set" in the command, which would clear the bundle contents every time and replace it with the last item in the chest. (also tried using "append" and the other ones but compared to "set" they didn't even change the bundle contents)